# Shell script cut returning empty string

Tags: sh

I am writing a script that I am trying to get the linux distribution. I have the following code but it is returning an empty string. I am sure I am missing something

```
OS=`cat /etc/os-release | grep -sw NAME`
NEWOS=$OS | `cut -d \" -f2`

echo $NEWOS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Honesty's answer says, you have two problems. Adding to his answer, I'd also like to address the use of backticks in your code.

The command substitution can be done in two ways one is using `$(command)` and the other is `` `command` ``. Both work the same, but the `$(command)` form is the *modern* way and has more clarity and readability.

> The real advantage of `$(...)` is not readability (that's a matter of taste, I'd say), but the ability to *nest* command substitutions *without escaping*, and to not have to worry about additionally having to escape `$` and `\` instances. - [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)

The following code uses the *modern* way:

```
#!/bin/bash

OS=$(cat /etc/os-release | grep -sw NAME)

NEWOS=$(echo "$OS" | cut -d \" -f2)

echo $OS
echo $NEWOS
```

Output on my computer:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
Ubuntu
```

Comment: @mklement0 Quick question: My original answer, before the edits, said that `$()` was part of the POSIX standard. But I was unsure so I edited that part of the answer. Is `$()` part of the POSIX standard? Oh and would you mind if I added your comment to my answer?

Comment: Yes, backticks are now deprecated.

Comment: But you actually can nest backticks; Jonny is right about `$()` existing solely for the purpose of readability. Try running `echo \`echo \\`echo foo\\`\``.

Comment: @JonnyHenly: Both `$(...)` and `\`...\`` are part of the POSIX standard - see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03

Comment: @Honesty: While the `$(...)` syntax has the advantages I've stated over `\`...\``, the latter is _not_  deprecated (nothing in the POSIX spec. says so).

Comment: @mklement0 Deprecation is the discouragement of usage but continued availability of a feature.

Comment: From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_06_03: "Because of these inconsistent behaviors, the backquoted variety of command substitution is not recommended for new applications that nest command substitutions or attempt to embed complex scripts."

Comment: @Honesty: Yes, you can nest the backtick syntax, but, as you've discovered, but it requires `\ `-escaping; similarly, `$` and `\ ` itself must be `\ `-escaped - neglecting to do so can have surprising results (e.g., `echo \$HOME`). You don't have to worry about that with the `$(...)` syntax.

Comment: @Honesty: That is a _qualified recommendation_ (emphasis mine: "not recommended for new applications _that nest command substitutions or attempt to embed complex scripts_", which is not quite the same thing as _deprecation_, but I fully agree that `$(...)` is the better choice.

Comment: @Honesty: You're missing a crucial implication: deprecation is _often_ - albeit not necessarily - a precursor to _removal_ of a feature, which is clearly not the case here. As long as we agree that the quoted passage says "Use this only in simple cases, avoid it in complex cases" rather than "This feature is obsolescent, it may go away", we're in agreement overall.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems.

1. Typing just `$OS` doesn't output anything to stdout (which is piped to `cut`).
2. Your second problem is that you put `cut` in backticks. This means that you're trying to *run* the output of an empty cut.

The solution is to write `$(echo "$OS" | cut -d \" -f2)`

Comment: ++, but to promote good habits I suggest recommending (a)  not to use all-uppercase names (e.g., `$os` instead of `$OS), and (b) to double-quote variable references.

Comment: This is one of the few cases where the quotes don't matter, so I didn't include them, but you're quite right about good practice. I've edited them in.

Answer (score 2):

To *complement* the existing, helpful answers with an *alternative* way to solve the problem, using a single `awk` command:

```
os=$(awk -F\" '/^NAME=/ { print $2 }' /etc/os-release)
echo "$os"
```

Note that I've changed the case of the variable from `OS` to `os`, because it's better not to use all-uppercase shell-variable names in order to  [avoid conflicts with environment variables and special shell variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01).