# Bash script Using a variable in awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a variable LINE and want to use it with awk to pull out the contents of the line numbered LINE from table.txt and make that a new variable called NAME which is then used to grep another file.

```
NAME=`awk 'FNR==$LINE' < table.txt`
echo "this is $NAME"
```

Seems to be close, but not quite the syntax.

If I use:

```
NAME=`awk 'FNR==1' < table.txt`
echo "this is $NAME"
```

Then echo gives me the first line of table.txt, if I use 2 I get the 2nd line, 3 the 3rd line, then I stopped variations.

Thanks for any advice.
EDITed first post formatting faux pas.

Comment: Those "weird apostrophes" are called "backticks", and if you would take a moment to read about formatting code in your question you could get them to display correctly.

Comment: See: [How to use shell variables in awk script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19075671/3776858)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for:

```
NAME=`awk -v line="$LINE" 'FNR==line' < table.txt`
```

but the backticks notation is obsolete so this is better:

```
NAME=$(awk -v line="$LINE" 'FNR==line' < table.txt)
```

and you should never use all-upper-case for variable names unless they are exported (in shell) to avoid clashing with builtin names so really it should be:

```
name=$(awk -v line="$line" 'FNR==line' < table.txt)
```

but whatever you're doing is almost certainly the wrong approach and should be done entirely within awk. Make sure you fully understand everything discussed in [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) if you're considering using shell to manipulate text.

Comment: Backticks are not *deprecated*! At least not by POSIX. That's just a common rumor. But `$()` is definitely the better choise!

Comment: Actually the backticks appear in so much, important?, ancient? scripts, I'm afraid of the day when they deprecate and then consequently remove them.. :) Ok, you might argue that they will not upgrade bash in a nuclear power plant. But who knows...

Comment: Definitely! Not at last to ease the typing for the programmer.

Comment: ++; re deprecation debate: what's important is that backticks are _not_ deprecated in the sense of "this will stop working in a future version"; however, `$(...)` is a _more modern, superior alternative_; the Bash v4 man page simply calls backticks the "old-style  backquote form of substitution" (without mentioning deprecation); similarly, the POSIX standard also doesn't declare the syntax _deprecated_, but clearly recommends use of `$(...)` for nested substitutions and "complex scripts" - see the comment thread on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36732882/45375).

Comment: Yes that sounds appropriate! I admit that when reading - new - code backticks are kind of a low quality indicator for me. Mostly that continues with unquoted variables and so on. Any new code should use `$()` instead of backticks.

Comment: updated my answer to say obsolete instead of deprecated and yes, use of backticks is a red flag that someone doesn't know what they're doing just like unquoted variables, UUOC, and multiple other oddities. Deleting my comments now.

Comment: I would keep them. It's an interesting discussion and good reference. (But I'm fine with whatever you prefer)

Comment: I'm afraid "obsolete" isn't really the right word either, because it implies "no longer in use". "Obsolescent" is slightly better, but still implies that it is in the _process of_ going away, which probably won't happen in this case. I can't really think of a single English word that pithily conveys "won't break if you use it, but it's better not to use it anymore".

Comment: keeping backticks, and other old fashioned styles supported is a help to novices like me a month into programming after a 20 year hiatus (from BASIC) as we google for answers to questions, and gradually learn to do things the modern way. 

It is pretty frustrating to be using a years old reply to our latest question which has a ton of votes but doesn't seem to work anymore. And thanks for the advice.

Comment: Someone was still using BASIC 20 years ago??? It's been 35 years since I last programmed in it and I thought it was dying then... :-).

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Ed Morton's helpful `awk`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37469503/45375):

If you only need to extract a single line by index, `sed` allows for a more concise solution that is also easier to optimize (note that I've changed the variable names to avoid [all-uppercase variable names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01)):

```
name=$(sed -n "$line {p;q;}")
```

- `-n` tells `sed` not to print (possibly modified) input lines by default
- `$line`, assuming this shell variable expands it to a positive integer (see caveat below), only matches the input line with that (1-based) index.
- `{p;q;}`, prints (`p`) the matching line, then exits the overall script immediately (`q`) as an optimization (no need to read the remaining lines).

Note:

- For more complex `sed` scripts it is NOT a good idea to use a double-quoted shell string with shell-variable expansion as the `sed` script, because understanding what is interpreted by the shell up front vs. what `sed` ends up seeing as a result can become confusing.
- Heed Ed's point that you're likely better off solving your problem with `awk` alone, given that `awk` can do its own regex matching (probably no need for `grep`).